# underline only selected words in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I created a button `underline` by clicking this button the entire text inside the `Entry` gets underlined. But 
I want only those words to be underlined which are selected by my cursor.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as tkFont
root = tk.Tk()


text = tk.Entry()
text.pack()

def underline():
    f = tkFont.Font(text, text.cget("font"))
    f.configure(underline = True)
    text.configure(font=f)


underline =tk.Button(root,text="underline",command=underline)
underline.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It gets underlined because You set the whole font to `f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pretty easy way of doing that (it will also ununderline it if selection is already underlined) also can't do this with Entry:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Text, Button
from _tkinter import TclError


root = Tk()

text = Text(root)
text.pack()


def underline():
    try:
        if text.tag_nextrange('underline_selection', 'sel.first', 'sel.last') != ():
            text.tag_remove('underline_selection', 'sel.first', 'sel.last')
        else:
            text.tag_add('underline_selection', 'sel.first', 'sel.last')
            text.tag_configure('underline_selection', underline=True)
    except TclError:
        pass


underline_btn = Button(root, text="underline", command=underline)
underline_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

So basically what happens is when calling the function it first looks if in the selection there already is an underlined tag (tag names can be what You want they are not predetermined by tkinter) and if it is clear the underline for the selection if not (so all the selected characters are not underlined) it applies underline.

try except is there to catch an error in case user presses a button without selection.

Comment: i wan to ask you also how to change color using this method beacuse i tried but nothing is happening i used ```colorchooser``` to select color and stored the value in var ```color_var``` after this i used ```text.tag_add(color_var, 'sel.first', 'sel.last')  
       text.tag_configure(color_var, fg=color_var)``` but Nothing is happening

Comment: @satyamjha You have to use keyword `foreground` because `fg` wont work

Comment: Thank you so much this is working ```foreground = color_var``` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't underline certain words in an Entry widget. But you can underline some words in a Text widget by using tags. All you have to do is find the words that need to be underlined and then add them with tags. Probably the easiest way is to tokenize the whole entry and add it piecewise, underlining just the predefined words:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as tkFont
root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(width=30,height=1,font=("Arial",11))
text.tag_configure("underlined",font=("Arial",11,"underline"))
text.pack()

def underline():
    words = ["hello","world"]
    content = text.get(1.0,tk.END+"-1c").split(' ')
    text.delete(1.0,tk.END)
    for c in content:
        if c in words:
            text.insert(tk.END,c, "underlined")
        else:
            text.insert(tk.END,c)
        text.insert(tk.END,' ')
    text.delete(tk.END+"-2c")
    
underline =tk.Button(root,text="underline",command=underline)
underline.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The expression `tk.END+"-1c"` means that the last character (a line break) is omitted from the content. Likewise, the expression `text.delete(tk.END+"-2c")` removes the last two characters (a trailing blank and a line break).

Comment: So using this it is possible to underline only the words that are in the `words` list?

Comment: Yes. You can try it. Write any text that contains the words "hello" or "world" and they will be underlined. All others won't.

Comment: That I noticed but that is a bit impractical isn't it?

Comment: Ah, my bad. I misread and thought they just wanted to underline _certain_ words. In order to underline words that are currently selected in the widget, Matiiss' solution is the one to use, of course.

Comment: oh, ok, but actually I thought about it and it could still be possible to use Your solution if only there was a way to automatically append words to the list for example through selection word would be appended (or more like overwrite) the list and be underlined using the current code

Comment: That would be possible. Just get the selection and use it as reference. So, if you select one instance of the word 'hello' it will be highlighted throughout the document.

Comment: Actually yeah, applying to all matching words a particular style could also be useful in some cases